# Активация виндовс старым ключом

Tags: windows, активация

У меня есть ПК с Windows 7.
Я хочу купить ноут, но на нем нет системы. Могу ли я поставить Windows 10 и активировать её старым ключом от семёрки? Если да, то не будет ли от этого плохо компу (в смысле, что нибудь изменится или нет)?

Comment: не активируется

Comment: Блин, а винда то дорогая...

Comment: Нет, просто потому что на свежий ноут 7 не установится. Перенести активацию другим способом? Ну там вроде через телефон можно или типа того.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, к сожалению приобретенным ключем от Windows 7, у вас не удастся активировать Windows 10.

> СОВЕТ:
>
> Как в качестве дешевого варианта приобретения ключа Windows 10, могу
> предложить купить его на Ebay.
>
> Стоимость такого продукта обычно варьируется от 4 до 20 долларов.